# EF code-first Many to Many Update

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two models that they are related `many-to-many`

**Doctors Model**

```
public class Doctor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Speciality> SelectedSpecialities { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Speciality> AllSpecialities { get; set; }
    public virtual List<int> PostedSpecialities { get; set; }
    public Doctor()
    {
        SelectedSpecialities = new List<Speciality>();
        PostedSpecialities = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

**Specialty Model**

```
public class Specialty
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Doctor> Doctors { get; set; }
}
```

I also have this fluent code to create many to many relation.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Speciality>().HasMany(x => x.Doctors).WithMany(x => x.SelectedSpecialities).Map(x =>
        {
            x.ToTable("DoctorsSpecialities");
            x.MapLeftKey("SpecialityId");
            x.MapRightKey("DoctorId");
        });
```

I can add `Doctor` just fine but when I attempt to `Update` Doctor's specialties it looks like EF doesn't remove previous relations.

I mean if I had  (1,2) and (1,3) and want to update it with (1,1) it doesn't remove (1,2) and (1,3) rows and I will have (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) at the end.

**Update Method**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(Doctor m)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Entry(m).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            m.SelectedSpecialities.Clear();
            // the line below returns a List<Specialty> of selected pecialties
            m.SelectedSpecialities = context.Specialities.Where(x => m.PostedSpecialities.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: I am not c# expert, but i think you are not telling the code to delete the previous record [(1,2) and (1,3)] and insert new one [(1,1)] or just update the record [(1,2)] to [(1,1)]. You are just writing code to insert new record.

Comment: I think EF supposed to bind my model to database and will take care of deleting those rows. 
even if I want to delete those rows by my self I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by fact that not every property in your entity classes is virtual. Try this out (works for me):

```
public class Doctor
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Fullname { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Specialty> SelectedSpecialities { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Specialty> AllSpecialities { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<int> PostedSpecialities { get; set; }
}

public class Specialty
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Doctor> Doctors { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Add(Doctor m)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        context.Entry(m).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        m.SelectedSpecialities.Clear();
        // the line below returns a List<Specialty> of selected pecialties
        foreach(var speciality in context.Specialties.Where(x => m.PostedSpecialities.Contains(x.Id)))
        {
            m.SelectedSpecialities.Add(speciality);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    return View();
}
```

By making all properties in entity class virtual the entity may be tracked by ef mechanisms and they will initialize properly navigation properties lists without you. You are generally allowed to use List<> as types of navigation properties but I prefer to use there ICollection instead as class shouldn't be dependent on other classes but on interfaces. If you use PostedSpecialities to only get values from the view and not to store it in db then I do not think it is good idea to mix it with properties being stored in db.